# CakePHP 3 hasMany shows IDs

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have 4 tables `orders`, `order_details`, `stocks`, and `units`.
Currently `stocks` and `units` belong to `order_details` which works perfectly. But `orders` has many `order_details` and the relationship is there but in cakephp it's showing the id's for the `order_details` not the names for units and stocks like when viewing a singular order_detail.

This is viewing a single order detail as you can see the unit name is showing and clickable
[image]
This is an order showing related `order_details` and you can see that for uni the id is being shown not the name of the unit.
[image]

My OrderDetailsTable.php initialize

```
public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->table('order_details');
        $this->displayField('id');
        $this->primaryKey('id');

        $this->belongsTo('Units', [
            'foreignKey' => 'unit_id'
        ]);
        $this->belongsTo('Orders', [
            'foreignKey' => 'order_id'
        ]);
        $this->belongsTo('Stocks', [
            'foreignKey' => 'stock_id'
        ]);
    }
```

and OrdersTable.php initialize

```
public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->table('orders');
        $this->displayField('order_number');
        $this->primaryKey('order_number');

        $this->belongsTo('Suppliers', [
            'foreignKey' => 'supplier_id'
        ]);
        $this->belongsTo('Users', [
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
        ]);
        $this->belongsTo('OrderMethods', [
            'foreignKey' => 'order_method_id'
        ]);
        $this->hasMany('OrderDetails', [
            'foreignKey' => 'order_id'
        ]);
    }
```

Part of the view.ctp getting the `order_details` data in orders

```
<?php foreach ($order->order_details as $orderDetails): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?= h($orderDetails->id) ?></td>
                <td><?= h($orderDetails->unit_id) ?></td>
                <td><?= h($orderDetails->order_id) ?></td>
                <td><?= h($orderDetails->stock_id) ?></td>
                <td><?= h($orderDetails->description) ?></td>
                <td><?= h($orderDetails->quantity_ordered) ?></td>
                <td><?= h($orderDetails->price) ?></td>
                <td><?= h($orderDetails->quantity_arrived) ?></td>
                <td><?= h($orderDetails->line_total) ?></td>
                <td><?= h($orderDetails->date) ?></td>
                <td><?= h($orderDetails->notes) ?></td>
                <td><?= h($orderDetails->eta) ?></td>
                <td><?= h($orderDetails->requested_by) ?></td>
                <td><?= h($orderDetails->requested_due_date) ?></td>
                <td class="actions">
                    <?= $this->Html->link(__('View'), ['controller' => 'OrderDetails', 'action' => 'view', $orderDetails->id]) ?>
                    <?= $this->Html->link(__('Edit'), ['controller' => 'OrderDetails', 'action' => 'edit', $orderDetails->id]) ?>
                    <?= $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'), ['controller' => 'OrderDetails', 'action' => 'delete', $orderDetails->  id], ['confirm' => __('Are you sure you want to delete # {0}?', $orderDetails->detail_id)]) ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I’m not very clear what you want to happen here. You’re echoing the unit ID, so of course it shows the ID rather than the name.

Comment: Please show your `find()` query. Chances are you just need to contain `OrderDetails.Units` and then echo `$orderDetails->unit->name`

Comment: @BadHorsie Awesome thanks that has fixed it!